# Configuration for PowerShell module created via .NET framework

Tags: wcf, powershell, configuration, module

What's the best practice when you have dependencies that you want to be able to configure when creating a PowerShell module in C#?

My specific scenario is that the PowerShell module I am creating via C# code will use a WCF service.  Hence, the service's URL must be something that the clients can configure.

Is there a standard approach on this?  Or will this be something that must be custom implemented?

Comment: Add `Uri` parameter to your cmdlet and provide a default value for it, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat standard way to do this is to allow a value to be provided as a parameter or default to reading special variable via PSCmdlet's `GetVariableValue`. This is what the built-in `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet does. It reads the variable PSEmailServer if no server is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding your question. So I'll posit a few scenarios:

1. You PS module will always use the same WCF endpoint. In that case you could hardcode the URL in the module
2. You have a limited number of endpoints to choose from, and there's some algorithm or best practice to associate an endpoint with a particular user, such as the closest geographically, based on the dept or division the user is in, etc.
3. It's completely up to the end user's preference to choose a URL.

For case #2, I suggest you implement the algorithm/best practice and save the result someplace - as part of the module install.

For case #3, using an environment variable seems reasonable, or a registry setting, or a file in one of the user's profile directories. Probably more important than where you persist the data though, is the interface you give users to change the setting. For example if you used an environment variable, it would be less friendly to tell the user to go to Control Panel, System, Advanced, Environment, User variable, New..., than to provide a simple PS function to change the URL. In fact I'd say providing a cmdlet/function to perform configuration is the closest to a "standard" I can think of.

Comment: Thanks.  #3 is what I'm referring to.  Would that be a better approach than providing a configuration file which reads WCF-related settings?

Comment: By "better", I'll assume you mean "Best practice". I don't have a strong sense of what that would be. Further I'd guess there's no clear winner. Many PS users are used to editing their profile, so a config file seems consistent with that. Better, provide a way for the user to put the setting in their profile. I use an alias `ep` to edit my profile, so putting the setting in the profile means I could still use my alias. But, I still think the UX (user experience) for setting the config is more important than the implementation. Besides hiding the implementation, you could also validate the URL.